# How to make popup to show normal text translation, not <kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput об'єкт в 0x0000000003FCC438>?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

My kivy pop-up outputs something like this:

```
<kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput об'єкт в 0x0000000003FC6358>
```

But I want it to be a translation.

This is my code:

```
from googletrans import Translator
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
lang = "uk"

class my(GridLayout, Widget):
    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):
       super(my, self).__init__( **kwargs)
       self.cols = 1
       self.inside= GridLayout()
       self.inside.cols=2

       self.inside.add_widget(Label(text= "Text:"))
       self.Text_that_we_need_to_translate = TextInput(multiline=True)
       self.inside.add_widget(self.Text_that_we_need_to_translate)

       self.add_widget(self.inside)
       self.submit= Button(text="submit", font_size=40)
       self.submit.bind(on_press=self.press)
       self.inside.add_widget(self.submit)
       self.clear = Button(text= "clear")
       self.clear.bind(on_press= self.clear_all)
       self.inside.add_widget(self.clear)

    def popup(self, res):
        self.popup_ = Popup(title='Translation:', content=Label(
            text = str(res.text)), size=(200,200), auto_dismiss=False)
        print(res.text)
        self.popup_.open(res)

    def clear_all(self,some):
        self.Text_that_we_need_to_translate.text= ""
        self.user_text = ""

    def press(self, of):
        global res
        text_ = str(self.Text_that_we_need_to_translate)
        tr = Translator()
        res = tr.translate(text_, dest=lang)
        self.popup(res)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return my()

if __name__== "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only problem is that you are passing the the string version of the `TextInput` widget to the translator. The line:

```
text_ = str(self.Text_that_we_need_to_translate)
```

just needs to be changed to:

```
text_ = str(self.Text_that_we_need_to_translate.text)
```

so that you are actually passing the text rather than the `TextInput` widget itself.